# Cmder cursor and highlight issues with Neovim

Tags: vim, neovim, conemu, cmder

[Currently in normal mode and the cursor is still just a | instead of the usual block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pHrI.png)

This doesn't change regardless of the mode, I have tried reinstalling both neovim and cmder and the same result happens regardless of the .vim file being used.

[using the / command to search for the word "there" and it makes the word im searching for invisible with or without a stock config for both cmder and neovim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9wTm.png)

[currently in visual select highlighting all of the text but the highlight on the text is clear/can't see it but it is working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Vc5.png)

For all of these issues I have tried using a new .vim file and a stock cmder config and have reinstalled both and the issue still occurs, the issue doesn't happen when I use neovim through the command prompt or from powershell.

Note:
The highlight issue doesn't occur when using regular vim through cmder only with Neovim, however the cursor staying a | persists in regular vim as well.

Update with regular vim:
Regular vim is working properly with highlighting cursor and everything, the issue only happens with neovim now, if this doesn't get fixed then ill just switch to regular vim.

Comment: I see no ConEmu status bar on your screenshots. I can't see the problem on your second screenshot. What version of neovim do you try? Windows binary, wsl, etc? Have you read docs? https://conemu.github.io/en/VimXterm.html

Answer (score 0):

I've never used cmder before, but for iterm2, for example, there is a setting associated to this:

[image]

If you're on osx you can hit <⌘ + ,> to get to the preferences for the current application.

Comment: @kurokashiro if I misunderstood your question - maybe this is what you're after https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes . (e.g.you can manipulate the cursor shape depending on mode)